Prove $K[X^{\alpha}:|\alpha|=m] \subset K[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ is normal.
Let $m \in \mathbb{N}$, $K$ is a field and $R=K[X^{\alpha}:|\alpha|=m] \subset K[x_1, \dots, x_n]$. Prove $R$ is normal.
Let $Frac(R)$ field of fractions of $R$ and $g \in Frac(R)$ integral over $R$. We need to prove $g \in R$. Then $g=\frac{p}{q}$ where $p \in R, q \in R\setminus \{0\} $ relative primes and $f(x) = {x^s}+ a_{s-1}x^{s-1}+ \dots + a_1s+a_0$, $a_i \in R$ such that $f(\frac{p}{q})=0$
Then $0=p^{s}+a_{s-1}p^{s-1}q + \dots + a_{1}pq^{s-1}+a_{0}q^{s}$. We have, $p^{s}, a_{0}q^{s}$ are polynomials with degree $ms$, and the other terms, each one has degree $m+(m(s-1))+m=ms+m$. Then the right side has degree $ms+m$.
But how can I afirm than $q=1$? Is the form that I could know $g \in R$
Other form that I think is use a shift, where I can see $R = \bigoplus_{l \geq 0} R_{lm}$ so, for all $f \in R$ can be written $f=f_{0m}+f_{1m}+ \dots +f_{km}$ where each $f_{im}$ is a homegenous polynomial with degree $im$. But again, I have a problem with the sum of $k-$ terms for $p$ and $q$. But maybe, this could help.

I wonder if it might be useful to use the fact that $K[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ is normal, so $g \in K[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$.  That would reduce to showing that the field of fractions of $R$, intersected with $K[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ within $K(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, gives back $R$.

Consider the localization of $R$ by $x_1^m$; this is isomorphic to $K[x_1^m, x_1^{-m}, x_2/x_1, x_3/x_1, \ldots, x_n/x_1]$, which is normal.  Therefore, for any $g$ in the integral closure of $R$, there is some $a$ such that $(x_1^m)^a g \in R$.  In other words, $g$ can be written as a linear combination of monomials $X^\alpha$ where $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{N}^{n-1}$ and $m \mid |\alpha|$.  However, we also have that $R\subseteq K[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ where $K[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ is normal, so we also have $g\in K[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$.  Using this, we can see that in fact, each monomial with a nonzero coefficient must have exponent in $\mathbb{N}^n$.  We can thus conclude that $g\in R$.

I'm sorry but I don't know what is a localization. Do you have any answer or suggestion with definition or something like that?

The localization I refer to is the subring of the field of fractions of $R$ which can be written as $\frac{f}{(x_1^m)^a}$ for some $f\in R, a\in \mathbb{N}$.

Sorry but I'm begging with this type of question how do you know that $K[x_1^m, x_1^{-m}, x_2/x_1, x_3/x_1, \ldots, x_n/x_1]$ is normal because it doesn't has the form $K[x_1,x_2,... x_n]$

And I have more questions but could give any reference to study or see what you talking about?

If you let $y_1 = x_1^m$ and otherwise $y_2 = x_2/x_1, \ldots, y_n = x_n/x_1$, then it's $K[y_1, y_1^{-1}, y_2, \ldots,  y_n]$ which is in fact a UFD, as a localization of a polynomial ring.  (And as for why a localization of a UFD is again a UFD -- it might help to think about the example of the ring of dyadic rational numbers, which is the localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ by adjoining an inverse of 2.  The essential idea is that you factor the numerator in the original ring, remove 2 or $y_1^{-1}$ from the factors since they become units, then the denominator also becomes a unit.)
